# Extending Spring's AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer disables my application logging

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logback

I am using Logback in my application.  Up until now, I've had a class implement WebApplicationInitializer so that my app starts up without web.xml.  Everything works fine up to that point and logging is visible in my console.  If I changed this so that my class extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and no longer implements WebApplicationInitializer directly, the logging seems to be turned off completely.  I don't get any logging whatsoever in my console.

I've played with it to be sure, switching between both implementations and it consistently behaves this way.  Has anybody seen this?  I don't see how it would impact my logging.

Here is my WebApplicationInitializer implementation

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(javax.servlet.ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(Application.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/*");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic hiddenHttpMethodFilter = servletContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", HiddenHttpMethodFilter.class);
        hiddenHttpMethodFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }
}
```

Here is the version that extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {Application.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/*"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] {new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()};
    }
}
```

In both cases, the application runs fine, but with the second version of my app initializer, I get no logging.

Comment: Also, the logging that is missing, is it missing for every logger or for a logger in particular?

Comment: Ok, it's been added.  And the logging is missing for all loggers, including the root logger which logs to a file.  The file doesn't get appended.